# How can I stop getting the first top column bar

Tags: reactjs

[image]

How may I make the chart data start from the beginning? The issue happends because the first column doesn't have a value, how may I cut off the first column?

```js
    const data = {
      labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)], // HERE
      datasets: this.alphabetDefined.map(value => {
        let color = this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.DEFAULT
      return{
        label: this.state.rows[0][value],
        data: this.state.rows.map(x => x[value]),
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`
      }})
    };
```

Comment: Can you filter the rows so it won't contain the first one ?

Comment: @Axnyff I'm not sure what you mean can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the rows that are undefined:

```
const filteredRows = this.state.rows.filter(row => row.A !== undefined);
const data = {
  labels: [filteredRows.map(x => x.A)],
  datasets: this.alphabetDefined.map(value => {
    let color = this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.DEFAULT
  return{
    label: filteredRows[0][value],
    data: filteredRows.map(x => x[value]),
    backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`
  }})
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could [`shift`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) the array and use the result:

```
const usedRows = [...this.state.rows]
usedRows.shift()

const data = {
  labels: [...usedRows.map(x => x.A)], // HERE
  ...
}
```

That will work in this instance when you want to cut out the first item.  If you want something more generic that cuts out any empty array elements, you can filter it before mapping it:

```
labels: [...this.state.rows.filter(row => row.A).map(x => x.A)], // HERE
```

`filter(row => row.A)` Means the returned array will only contain entries where `row` has an A property that is defined.  I'm not sure what your filtering according to (`A` or some other value), but this will work too.

Comment: When I try the first example I get an error `TypeError: usedRows.map is not a function or its return value is not iterable`.
When I try the second one I'm getting rhe wrong `data`

Comment: A photo of the second example you sent with the filter.

https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1471/9960900438.png

Comment: `shift` mutate the array and returns the first value removed.

Comment: @Axnyff Can you provide an example?

Comment: oops yes that's right.  you don't want the returned value, you just want the result.  let me edit my answer

Comment: It still doesn't start from the beginning and it doesn't get the data of the fist column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'start from the beginning' or 'get the data of the first column'.  Your best bet is to use the `filter` method to filter out undefined rows, like my second option or like @Axnyff's answer recommends.